# Inheritance and a constructor with a parameter

Tags: scala

I have a class:

```
class BaseClass(val a: Int) {
 //....
}
```

And a child class which can be represented by 2 ways:

```
class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
 //...
}
```

or

```
class ChildClass(a: Int) extends BaseClass(a) {
   // if I use val keyword, it doesn't change anything -- the error remains  
   //...
 }

// the error:
//overriding value a in class BaseClass of type Int;
//[error]  value a needs `override' modifier
```

In both cases I have an error(s) so that I can't even compile it.

How do I make it compile?

Comment: `class ChildClass(a: Int) extends BaseClass(a)` works for me in `2.10.1` and `2.9.3`. Add error text to your question.

Comment: Again, what's the error?

Comment: @MariusKavansky: I've copied `class BaseClass(val a: Int)` from question, so I couldn't forget about `val`.

Comment: @senia Блин, я не на тот класс смортел у себя. Все, спасибо.

Comment: @MariusKavansky: Please, change your question to indicate that the problem is fixed.

Comment: @MariusKavansky I have to note that [use of languages other than english is discouraged on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/167396). (*пожалуйста, используйте английский*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no problems with your code. `class ChildClass(a: Int) extends BaseClass(a)` works fine. The problem it somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

First, in your situation you can't extend your `BaseClass` with the construct

```
class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
...
}
```

because you are not providing an argument for BaseClass' constructor.

You should do something like:

```
val myVal: Int = 5;

class ChildClass extends BaseClass(myVal) {
...
}
```

(your latter extension form is correct, by the way).

Second (and the nature of your problem), you cannot specify the same parameter list signature for `ChildClass`' constructor without adding the `override` modifier, this way:

```
class ChildClass(override val a: Int) extends BaseClass(a) {
...
}
```

Comment: `class ChildClass(a: Int) extends BaseClass(a)` [works fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913492/inheritance-and-a-constructor-with-a-parameter/16914158#comment24413527_16913975).

Answer (score 1):

Declaring `ChildClass` as

```
class ChildClass(val a: Int) extends BaseClass(a)
```

means that you (try to) introduce the private field `ChildClass.a`. Since `BaseClass.a` is already declared, the error tells you that you need to explicitly state that you want to override `BaseClass.a`, i.e.,

```
class ChildClass(override val a: Int) extends BaseClass(a)
```

You can avoid this by

a) renaming the newly introduced variable, e.g.,

```
class ChildClass(val _a: Int) extends BaseClass(_a)
```

b) or by declaring, but not defining it, in `BaseClass`. This, however, works only if `BaseClass` can be abstract:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
  def a: Int
}

class ChildClass(val a: Int) extends BaseClass
```

Comment: Did you manage to reproduce the problem? `class ChildClass(a: Int) extends BaseClass(a)` works fine. There is a mistake in the question. The author [used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913492/inheritance-and-a-constructor-with-a-parameter?noredirect=1#comment24413232_16913492) wrong class name.

Comment: why? `class ChildClass(_a: Int) extends BaseClass(_a)` -- it works fine with `a`.

Comment: @senia You are right, the problem occurs only with `class ChildClass(val a: Int) extends BaseClass(a)`, not with `class ChildClass(a: Int) ...`. The reason for this is, that the latter declaration does not entail declaring a field `a`, just a local variable that passed on to the super constructor. See the output of `scala -print`.